# How can we stop the div tag to be empty in Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am following this example

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

If you go to their example and click on Tab1 and Tab2 , then immediately the text disapperas and div box becomes small and then new data is loaded.

Is there any way

1. Old data should only gets replaced when new data is there. Or they should fade in and fade out with no delay
2. The Div box should not shrink , the height should stay same or min height

Answer (score 0):

To the first question:
You could select another tab if an ajax error occurs. Unfortunately I was not able to save the "last successfully loaded tab". But if a "default tab" is enough: 
[you can look here](http://jsfiddle.net/L95UP/7/)

To your second question: The tabs have a class `ui-tabs-panel`. You can style it as you want. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L95UP/5/).

Comment: The problem in first case is not the ajax error but the time lag between having empty div box and loading the new data . that time is 4-5 seconds

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood you. I don't think jquery-ui-tabs provides a solution for this problem. You could write your own little tab-plugin (or take one from the web). Nevertheless, I would think the user expects the tab to change as soon as he clicks on it. Even if he only sees a "loading" animation.